# Hardening wordpress on IIS7+ web.config equivalent of .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, security, .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting

On Linux servers, we can benefit from .htaccess rules in order to make wordpress installations more secure.

How is that possible on IIS7+?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Better WP Security .htaccess rules and the rule converter wizard on IIS Manager, I got the following for the **web.config** file.

This file includes:

- usual wordpress rewrite
- denying blacklisted agents
- file leeching protection
- trace | delete | track protection
- forbidden access to some directories

In addition to these, another tip: wordpress does work if you move your wp-config.php file one level up (Do not keep it under /www/)

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>

    <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
     <match url="*" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="Abuse Agent Blocking from HackRepair.com" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^.*" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <!--# BEGIN Better WP Security-->
            <!--# Begin HackRepair.com Blacklist-->
            <!--# Abuse Agent Blocking-->
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^BlackWidow" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Bolt\ 0" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Bot\ mailto:craftbot\@yahoo\.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="CazoodleBot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^ChinaClaw" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Custo" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Default\ Browser\ 0" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^DIIbot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^DISCo" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="discobot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Download\ Demon" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^eCatch" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ecxi" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^EirGrabber" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^EmailCollector" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^EmailSiphon" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^EmailWolf" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Express\ WebPictures" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^ExtractorPro" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^EyeNetIE" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^FlashGet" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^GetRight" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^GetWeb!" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Go!Zilla" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Go-Ahead-Got-It" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^GrabNet" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Grafula" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="GT::WWW" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="heritrix" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^HMView" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="HTTP::Lite" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="HTTrack" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ia_archiver" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="IDBot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="id-search" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="id-search\.org" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Image\ Stripper" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Image\ Sucker" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Indy\ Library" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^InterGET" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Internet\ Ninja" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^InternetSeer\.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="IRLbot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ISC\ Systems\ iRc\ Search\ 2\.1" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Java" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^JetCar" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^JOC\ Web\ Spider" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^larbin" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^LeechFTP" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="libwww" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="libwww-perl" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Link" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="LinksManager.com_bot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="linkwalker" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="lwp-trivial" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Mass\ Downloader" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Maxthon$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="MFC_Tear_Sample" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^microsoft\.url" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Microsoft\ URL\ Control" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^MIDown\ tool" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Mister\ PiX" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Missigua\ Locator" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Mozilla\.*Indy" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Mozilla\.*NEWT" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^MSFrontPage" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Navroad" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^NearSite" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^NetAnts" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^NetSpider" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Net\ Vampire" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^NetZIP" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Nutch" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Octopus" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Offline\ Explorer" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Offline\ Navigator" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^PageGrabber" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="panscient.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Papa\ Foto" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^pavuk" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="PECL::HTTP" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^PeoplePal" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^pcBrowser" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="PHPCrawl" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="PleaseCrawl" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^psbot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^RealDownload" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^ReGet" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Rippers\ 0" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="SBIder" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^SeaMonkey$" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^SiteSnagger" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^SmartDownload" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Snoopy" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Steeler" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^SuperBot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^SuperHTTP" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Surfbot" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^tAkeOut" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Teleport\ Pro" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Toata\ dragostea\ mea\ pentru\ diavola" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="URI::Fetch" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="urllib" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="User-Agent" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^VoidEYE" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Web\ Image\ Collector" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Web\ Sucker" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Web\ Sucker" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="webalta" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebAuto" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="WebCollage" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebCopier" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebFetch" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebGo\ IS" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebLeacher" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebReaper" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebSauger" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Website\ eXtractor" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Website\ Quester" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebStripper" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebWhacker" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WebZIP" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Wells\ Search\ II" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="WEP\ Search" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Wget" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Widow" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WWW-Mechanize" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^WWWOFFLE" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Xaldon\ WebSpider" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="zermelo" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Zeus" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^Zeus\.*Webster" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="ZyBorg" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^wp-admin/includes/" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <!--# RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]-->
            <add input="{SCRIPT_FILENAME}" pattern="^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Imported Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Imported Rule 5" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^wp-includes/theme-compat/" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="Imported Rule 6" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
        </rule>

     </rules>           
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```